# Datepicker, set default value in input box

Tags: jquery, html, date, datepicker

I use htm5 input type date, but as does not work in all browsers I add Jquery for those.
So if browser does not accept type="date", then it is a type="text" as below.

I want the input to have a default value instead of an empty box.
I have managed to add a default date value, but I don´t like it that way, I want the default date displayed same as in html5, like this: dd/mm/2016 (not displaying day or month, the letters instead) or if not possible some text.
This is the code:

```
<input type="date" name="llegada" class="date" id="datellegada"
min="2016-04-07" max="2016-12-31" value="">

(function() {
   var elem = document.createElement('input');
   elem.setAttribute('type', 'date');
   if ( elem.type === 'text' ) {
       $.datepicker.setDefaults({
           dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
           regional: 'en',
       })
       $('#datellegada').datepicker().datepicker('setDate', new Date());
       $('#datellegada').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(2016, 3, 1));
       $('#datellegada').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date(2017,0,
        6));
   }
   // ... ?
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this solution :

```
$('.datellegada').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```